# importing requests module does not work how to make it work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-requests

i run the command bellow on widows command line
`pip install requests`

the error that apeared is :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1265, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    next = lambda o: o.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'charset-normalizer ~=2.0.0', 'at', ' ~=2.0.0')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\mchaa\pip\pip.log
```

ps: i tried to install it from github and the same error every time i don't know how to fix it

Comment: How did you install `requests`? The error message looks like its coming from the packaging infrastructure, not `requests` itself.

Comment: Could this be because of a dependency (I see charset-normalizer) that is not Python 2 compatible? (Charset-normalizer 2.0.0 does not list Python 2.7 as compatible.)

Comment: Try installing an older version of charset-normalizer that is Python 2 compatible, then install a version of requests that can use that version of charset-normalizer (that is, without automatically upgrading it upon installation).

Comment: Or see if you can use a newer version of Python. Python 2 is not supported anymore.

Comment: @9769953 can't use another version bcuz i'm working with oodo 8 wich required this version of python

Comment: And is your quests installation related to your Oodo installation?

Comment: @9769953 I need to create a oodo module tht will use an api requested by python at first step i found that i should use requests module in python so that i tried to use it with python2.7 i hope i could make u understand what i need

Answer (score 0):

**solution :**
i use the command bellow to uninstall

1. uninstall current pip:

`python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools`

2. download get-pip.py from [https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py%20instead.)
   after downloding it put it in the same folder that excute the python's command
3. execute get-pip script:

`python get-pip.py`